# StandardError shows but StandardOutput doesn't when calling a Process in C#

Tags: c#, python, process, invalidoperationexception, redirectstandardoutput

Below is a call to a Python process but it doesn't return the `StandardOutput`. I intently made a typo inside the Python file and it successfully returned the `StandardError`.

```
        string pythonExe = @"../../../Vokaturi/python.exe";

        string pythonFile = @"../../../Vokaturi/test.py";

        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pythonExe);

        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = pythonFile;

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
        myProcess.Start();

        StreamReader myStreamReaderError = myProcess.StandardError;
        string myErrorString = myStreamReaderError.ReadToEnd();

        StreamReader myStreamReaderOutput = myProcess.StandardError;
        string myOutputString = myStreamReaderOutput.ReadToEnd();
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        myProcess.Close();
```

That means the way I call the files in their paths are correct. I also tried it in command prompt and it returns the necessary output without error. When I debug the code, it says it threw an exception of type `system.invalidoperationexception` (after `myProcess.start()`).

[image]

But it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151903/invalid-operation-exception-from-c-sharp-process-class) that it's expected. What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading only standard error  for the readeroutput too

```
 StreamReader myStreamReaderError = myProcess.StandardError;
    string myErrorString = myStreamReaderError.ReadToEnd();

    StreamReader myStreamReaderOutput = myProcess.StandardError;
    string myOutputString = myStreamReaderOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

change it too

```
StreamReader myStreamReaderError = myProcess.StandardError;
    string myErrorString = myStreamReaderError.ReadToEnd();

    StreamReader myStreamReaderOutput = myProcess.StandardOutput;
    string myOutputString = myStreamReaderOutput.ReadToEnd();
```